# Mysql does not commit changes after setting character set

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I am trying to set character set server by using `set character_set_server = utf8;` (it's originally utf8mb4) after I logged in to MySQL using `mysql -u root -p` (I also tried another user and also specified a DB with `--database`). After running the `set` command I checked the variable by using `show variables like "%charac%"`. It shows the correct value as *utf8*. However, after I quit the session and re-logged in and rechecked the variable it shows utf8mb4. I also tried running `commit;` after setting character set, again it didn't change the value. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to "downgrade" the character set?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not a transaction. Transactions are used with DML (data modifying language) Statements (like select, insert, upate, delete). Therefore committing is not the right thing to do here.

Most variables have a global value and a value that's only valid for the current session. You can see that in the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server) (look at `scope`). When you don't specify that you want to change the global value, the session value is assumed.

Try with

```
set global character_set_server = 'utf8';
```

Add that change also to your `etc/my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section. Otherwise this change will be lost again, when you restart the mysql server (mysqld).

And finally, you might want to leave that at uft8mb4. You might think, that you don't need the additional byte, but keep in mind, that that additional byte is only used, when you really use a character like an emoji in your text. And performance-wise it actually performs better. I have no proof at hand here, but I was recently at a database conference, where one speech was about benchmark checks. There it said, it performs much better. The utf8 that was previously implemented by is a crippled utf8 that should die as soon as possible.

Comment: Possibly the conference quote is that utf8mb4 performance was _significantly_ improved in MySQL 8.0.  (At least, that's the way I heard it.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, in MySQL 8.0, but it also performs better than utf8. Should have clarified that more. Thanks.

Comment: As for "dies as soon as possible" -- I wholeheartedly agree.  Much of my 'Reputation' on this site comes from helping with Emoji, 767 index limit, Mojibake, etc.